# Strange behaviour of textedit.clear() in a PyQT5 app on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5, pyinstaller, qtextedit

I'm writing a simple PyQt5 application that processes plain text. I have some push buttons that clear the input window and paste from clipboard. I experience a very strange behaviour on Mac when I bundle my Python program into an app file using PyInstaller. When I click on the "Clear" button the input window is not cleared and the first character appears like half-cut and the line remains in input window. When I click "Paste" the previous text is not deleted but the cursor moves to the end of line and inserts that half-cut character. I have connected the same method of clearing the input window to the menuAction and, amazingly, it works flawlessly. Also, I can clear TextEdit by selecting all text and pressing Backspace and I can paste text into it by pressing `Ctrl+V`. When I run the script from the terminal it works perfectly well, but when I create an app executable these strange things start. It happens only on Mac. When I create an .exe file on Windows or run the script on Linux, everything is fine. What can be the reason for this? What I am doing wrong?

I have a separate ui file generated by Qt Designer and converted to py, and I have a MyScript.py file where I include all logic and connect buttons.

Here is my push buttons code:

```
self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.ui.textEdit.clear)
self.ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.ui.textEdit.paste)
```

I tried writing separate methods for `self.ui.textEdit.clear` and `self.ui.textEdit.paste` and call them from connect, but it didn't change anything.

Here are my menu actions:

```
self.ui.actionClear.triggered.connect(self.ui.textEdit.clear)
self.ui.actionPaste.triggered.connect(self.ui.textEdit.paste)
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57506101/qlabel-is-not-updated-unless-the-mainwindow-is-unfocused) help?

Comment: It seems that repaint() method worked! Thank you so much for your hint and help!